# No Map Shows If I Modify the Basemap on Esri-React-Boot

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am pretty stuck and do not know what I am doing wrong. I am currently just trying to modify this library from Esri (https://github.com/Esri/esri-react-boot).

It uses OAuth, but you can view the map without having to sign in. However, if I want to modify the `basemap` config to show `arcgis-topographic` like the tutorial shows here (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/display-a-map/), I do not get any render of the map.

The tutorial uses an API Key, but when using OAuth, you shouldn't need to do anything like that.

Below are the only 2 files I have modified, everything else is the same as in the repo.

config.json

```
{
  "appVersion": "2.0.0",

  "apiUrl": "api",
  "loginUrl": "api/auth/arcgis",
  "logoutUrl": "api/logout",
  "jsapiUrl": "https://js.arcgis.com/4.17/",
  "jsapiV4": true,

  "clientId": "<hidden>",

  "sessionId": "esri-react-boot_session",

  "mapConfig": {
    "basemap": "arcgis-topographic",
    "center": [-118.805, 34.027],
    "zoom": 13
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-jsapi-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@esri/arcgis-rest-auth": "^3.0.0",
    "@esri/arcgis-rest-portal": "^3.0.0",
    "@esri/arcgis-rest-request": "^3.0.0",
    "calcite-react": "^0.44.0",
    "esri-loader": "^2.16.0",
    "framer-motion": "^1.6.18",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">1%",
      "last 4 versions",
      "Firefox ESR",
      "not ie < 11"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Support for the new named basemaps was added in version 4.18.  
Your config.json mentions 4.17.

Comment: I tried setting it to 4.18, but said that version did not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#basemap

This shows the availability of basemaps depending on whether an API Key is used or not.

Comment: This is new, right?  I just saw the new product launch intro, which introduced the concept of using API keys for access to basemaps.  Did this exist before?

Comment: Honestly, I am unsure. This was given to me on the esri community forums.

Comment: Yes, API keys was introduced in January 2021.  https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/developers/developers/introducing-arcgis-platform/